# Trouble accessing data from java program

Tags: java, database, java-8

I'm having a goofy issue. I'm trying to see if I can printout the restaurants and employees data I have here and I can't remember how best to do it this.

Once I can figure out how to do that, I'll be able to create methods using it, but I can't seem to remember how to do it this way.

**Updated Code**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee john = new Employee("John","asian",35.00);
        Employee sam = new Employee("Sam","Greek",25.00);
        Employee michael = new Employee("Michael","Italian",50.00);

        Restaurant asian = new Restaurant("Asian","asian",25.00);
        Restaurant greek = new Restaurant("greek","greek",25.00);
        Restaurant italian = new Restaurant("italian","italian",25.00);


    }

    public static class Restaurant {

        private String restaurantName;
        private String cuisine;
        private double price;

        public Restaurant( String restaurantName,
                           String cuisine,
                           double price) {

            this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
            this.cuisine = cuisine;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getRestaurantName() {
            return restaurantName;
        }

        public String getCuisine() {
            return cuisine;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public static class Employee {

        private String employeeName;
        private String cuisine;
        private double budget;

        public Employee(String employeeName,
                        String cuisine,
                        double budget) {

            this.employeeName = employeeName;
            this.cuisine = cuisine;
            this.budget = budget;
        }

        public String getEmployeeName() {
            return employeeName;
        }

        public String getCuisine() {
            return cuisine;
        }

        public double getBudget() {
            return budget;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's really only three things you have to know to do this: 1) what information do you want to print? 
 2) how to use the getters on your `Employee` and `Restaurant` to extract out the stuff you want to print; and 3) how to print the stuff out once you've got it.  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: It depends on how you would like to print it, did you take a look at overriding the toString() method of the Object class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: @KevinAnderson I've implemented the toString() method in the classes but I need to be able to print out the information. Eventually I want to print out a recommendation based on budget and price. But for now, I just want to make sure I can print the info in the command line.

Comment: Does `System.out.println(...)` ring a bell?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I remember that, but for some reason I'm going to braindead as to what I should call from within there.

Comment: @KevinAnderson It just hit me. As I hit myself for forgetting something so basic. THanks

Answer (score 0):

For printing out the data of an object you can override the `toString` method.

After that, the class Restaurant looks like this.

```
public static class Restaurant {

        private String restaurantName;
        private String cuisine;
        private double price;

        public Restaurant( String restaurantName,
                           String cuisine,
                           double price) {
            this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
            this.cuisine = cuisine;
            this.price = price;

        }

        public String getRestaurantName() {
            return restaurantName;
        }

        public String getCuisine() {
            return cuisine;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Restaurant [restaurantName=" + restaurantName + ", cuisine=" + cuisine + ", price=" + price + "]";
        }
    }
```

the class Employee looks like this.

```
public static class Employee {

        private String employeeName;
        private String cuisine;
        private double budget;

        public Employee(String employeeName,
                        String cuisine,
                        double budget) {

            this.employeeName = employeeName;
            this.cuisine = cuisine;
            this.budget = budget;
        }

        public String getEmployeeName() {
            return employeeName;
        }

        public String getCuisine() {
            return cuisine;
        }

        public double getBudget() {
            return budget;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [employeeName=" + employeeName + ", cuisine=" + cuisine + ", budget=" + budget + "]";
        }
        
        
    }
```

and then you can print an object in sysout

```
System.out.println(michael);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a toString method() for each Object's class.

- For example in Employee Class:

```
public String toString()
{
     String str = "Employee Name: " + employeeName + 
          "\nCuisine: " + cuisine + "\nBudget: " + budget;
     
     return str;
}
```

After that you just have to use the toString() in the main() method:

```
System.out.println(john.toString());
```

In the main method you could also use an array to store the data and make it easier to access. Then to display both of the objects inside you could use just one for loop, but I used two to keep the outputs separate from one another.

```
int numEmployees = 3;
Employee myEmployees[] = new Employee[numEmployees];

myEmployees[0] = new Employee("John","asian",35.00); // Stores John in index 0...
myEmployees[1] = new Employee("Sam","Greek",25.00);
myEmployees[2] = new Employee("Michael","Italian",50.00);

// Displays each object who's index is associated with the value for i
for(int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
     System.out.println(myEmployees[i].toString()); 

int numRestaurants = 3;
Restaurant myRestaurants = new Restaurant[numRestaurant]

myRestaurants[0] = new Restaurant("Asian","asian",25.00); // Stores Asain in index 0...
myRestaurants[1] = new Restaurant("greek","greek",25.00);
myRestaurants[2] = new Restaurant("italian","italian",25.00);

// Displays each object who's index is associated with the value for i
for(int i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++)
     System.out.println(myRestaurants[i].toString());
```